# How to get installed packages using PackageManager?

Tags: android

I want to get a list of Installed apps, but **only the ones which have an icon and are launchable**. I am making a launcher app and using this:

```
  private List<AppList> getInstalledApps() {
    List<AppList> res = new ArrayList<AppList>();
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((isSystemPackage(p) == false)) {
            String appName = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
            Drawable icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
            String package_name = p.applicationInfo.packageName;
            res.add(new AppList(appName, package_name, icon));
        }
    }

private boolean isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
    return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) ? true : false;
}
```

The problem is, to filter out non launchable apps, I have to filter out system apps, which is not the best solution because it also filters out these apps: Camera, Calendar, Calculator etc.

Comment: Please don't change your question like that, especially after an answer has been posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if an app is launchable by

```
packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName) != null
```

For icons, you can check if

`info.loadIcon(packageManager) != null`.

Comment: how do I set a <list> in my listview adapter?

Comment: List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);